# HTML putting "chapters" on a table

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and I'm getting used to working with CSS.

My question is:

I would like to put a divider of different color and of a different text alignment.

Here is an exemple:
[image]

I would like to replicate "siege engines" and "heavy weapons"

What I've managed to do so far is this:

```
<style>
tr:nth-child(1) {background-color: #11599c}

tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #333333}

table
{
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: #666666;
    color: #ffffff
}
</style>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="divider">Divider</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But the divider is both left-aligned and gray:

[image]

What can I do to make it center-aligned and black?

**Note**: I've already answered my own question partially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this

```
.divider{
   text-align:center;
   background-color:black;
}
```

Example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qpakzqmg/).

Comment: mark it as the correct answer if it solved your problem.. and welcome. :)